# PostgreSQL Query WHERE date is greater than 3 years old

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, where-clause

I have a table that contains 4 dates:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    date date
);

    11-mar-2008
    25-now-2007
    18-apr-2012
    20-apr-2012
```

I need a query that returns all dates that are older than three-years-old. That should be the first 2 dates.

This doesn't work for me:

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE date = now()::-1095;
```

Answer (score 37):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  dates 
WHERE 
  date < now() - '3 years' :: interval;
```

Also, naming your column `date` is not a good practice, as this is a reserved word in PostgreSQL.

Comment: To nit-pick, it is a reserved word in the SQL standard, though PostgreSQL has not found it necessary to reserve it.  For portability and future-proofing it might still be wise to avoid using it as an identifier.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html