# How can I retrieve documents that are 3 days old?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How can I retrieve all documents that are 3 days old (from the date they were posted)?

Something similar to the SQL given at:
[Checking if date is more than 3 years old in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258680/checking-if-date-is-more-than-3-years-old-in-postgresql)

```
SELECT * FROM foos WHERE date < '3 days'::interval;
```

Comment: I don't actually know ruby, never programmed it, however can't you just the http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html with the mongoid representation of a ISODate?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({created_at : {$gt : <fill in the date of the day before three days back  in the right format> })
```

should work

Comment: I assume the field created_at exists in your document

Comment: I want to do this dynamically. As each result has its own created_at column